# RingCentral API Login returns Invalid response string

Tags: oauth-2.0, ringcentral

I created a `Server-only (No UI)` Private app, with Read Call Log Permission, and when the login is issued I get the following error:

`Exception: Invalid response string SDK HTTP Error at https:///platform.devtest.ringcentral.com/restapi/oauth/token Response text: 
Previous: Invalid response string #0 /srv/www/vhosts/internal.kingscredit.com/includes/ringcentral-php-master/vendor/ringcentral/ringcentral-php/src/Platform/Platform.php(214): 
RingCentral\SDK\Http\Client->send(Object(RingCentral\Psr7\Request)) 
\#1 /srv/www/vhosts/internal.kingscredit.com/includes/ringcentral-php-master/vendor/ringcentral/ringcentral-php/src/Platform/Platform.php(301): 
RingCentral\SDK\Platform\Platform->sendRequest(Object(RingCentral\Psr7\Request), 
Array) #2 /srv/www/vhosts/internal.kingscredit.com/includes/ringcentral-php-master/vendor/ringcentral/ringcentral-php/src/Platform/Platform.php(123): 
RingCentral\SDK\Platform\Platform->requestToken('/restapi/oauth/...', Array) #3 /srv/www/vhosts/internal.kingscredit.com/includes/ringcentral-php-master/demo/callRecording.php(25): 
RingCentral\SDK\Platform\Platform->login('+15188315198', 101, 'xxxxxxxxxxxx', true) #4 {main}`

**What am I missing? Why do I get this error? 
Here is the code:**

```
require_once('_bootstrap.php');

use RingCentral\SDK\SDK;

// Create SDK instance

$credentials = array(
    'username'     => '+15188315198',       // your RingCentral account phone number
    'extension'    => 101,              // or number
    'password'     => 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'appKey'       => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'appSecret'    => 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
    'server'       => 'https:platform.devtest.ringcentral.com',
    'dateFrom' => '1/1/2016'
); 

$rcsdk = new SDK($credentials['appKey'], $credentials['appSecret'], $credentials['server'], 'Demo', '1.0.0');

$platform = $rcsdk->platform();

$platform->login($credentials['username'], $credentials['extension'], $credentials['password'], true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you confirm, if you have installed our PHP SDK using Composer ?

If you have, could you confirm if the below mentioned steps are followed :

1.) Installing RingCentral PHP SDK using Composer

```
https://github.com/ringcentral/ringcentral-php#with-composer-recommended
```

2.) You would need to require the Composer's AutoLoader in your PHP Script.

```
require_once(__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php');
```

Lets say the folder structure looks like this as below :

> your application ( application name )
>       -vendor ( PHP SDK whihc is installed using Composer )
>       -index.php ( application's PHP Script )

Kindly include the "AutoLoader" within the index.php script inside your application.

Below is how the sample code would look like :

```
<?php 

require_once(__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php'); 

use RingCentral\SDK\SDK; 

// Create SDK instance 
$rcsdk = new SDK("appKey", "appSecret" , "https://platform.devetst.ringcentral.com", 'Demo', '1.0.0'); 

// Create Platform Singleton Instance 
$platform = $rcsdk->platform(); 

// Login 
$auth = $platform->login("Username", "extension", "password"); 

// Respsone 
print 'Login Success' . $auth->text() . PHP_EOL;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes I Installed RingCentral PHP SDK using Composer
2. I replaced the require_once('_bootstrap.php'); with require_once("vendor/autoload.php"); although that is what the demos use
   and I still get the error.
3. I tried the simple login example you included and I get the same error

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Invalid response string' in /srv/www/vhosts/internal.kingscredit.com/includes/ringcentral-php-master/vendor/ringcentral/psr7/src/functions.php:478 Stack trace: #0 /srv/www/vhosts/internal.kingscredit.com/includes/ringcentral-php-master/vendor/ringcentral/ringcentral-php/src/Http/ApiResponse.php(56): RingCentral\Psr7\parse_response('HTTP/1.1 0 OK\r\n') #1 /srv/www/vhosts/internal.kingscredit.com/includes/ringcentral-php-master/vendor/ringcentral/ringcentral-php/src/Http/Client.php(99): RingCentral\SDK\Http\ApiResponse->__construct(Object(RingCentral\Psr7\Request), false, 0) #2 /srv/www/vhosts/internal.kingscredit.com/includes/ringcentral-php-master/vendor/ringcentral/ringcentral-php/src/Http/Client.php(25): RingCentral\SDK\Http\Client->loadResponse(Object(RingCentral\Psr7\Request)) #3 /srv/www/vhosts/internal.kingscredit.com/includes/ringcentral-php-master/vendor/ringcentral/ringcentral-php/src/Platform/Platform.php(214): RingCentral\SDK\Http\Client-> in /srv/www/vhosts/internal.kingscredit.com/includes/ringcentral-php-master/vendor/ringcentral/ringcentral-php/src/Http/Client.php on line 44

Answer (score 0):

Could you verify if the `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` is set correctly.

You could ref to this issue for more info : 
[Setting CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER](https://github.com/ringcentral/ringcentral-php/issues/29)

Answer (score 0):

I added the curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); on line 73 of client.php and it made no difference.

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Invalid response string' in /srv/www/vhosts/internal.kingscredit.com/includes/ringcentral-php-master/vendor/ringcentral/psr7/src/functions.php:478 Stack trace: #0 /srv/www/vhosts/internal.kingscredit.com/includes/ringcentral-php-master/vendor/ringcentral/ringcentral-php/src/Http/ApiResponse.php(56): RingCentral\Psr7\parse_response('HTTP/1.1 0 OK\r\n') #1 /srv/www/vhosts/internal.kingscredit.com/includes/ringcentral-php-master/vendor/ringcentral/ringcentral-php/src/Http/Client.php(99): RingCentral\SDK\Http\ApiResponse->__construct(Object(RingCentral\Psr7\Request), false, 0) #2 /srv/www/vhosts/internal.kingscredit.com/includes/ringcentral-php-master/vendor/ringcentral/ringcentral-php/src/Http/Client.php(25): RingCentral\SDK\Http\Client->loadResponse(Object(RingCentral\Psr7\Request)) #3 /srv/www/vhosts/internal.kingscredit.com/includes/ringcentral-php-master/vendor/ringcentral/ringcentral-php/src/Platform/Platform.php(214): RingCentral\SDK\Http\Client-> in /srv/www/vhosts/internal.kingscredit.com/includes/ringcentral-php-master/vendor/ringcentral/ringcentral-php/src/Http/Client.php on line 44